# Java Reflections - Getting method with a specific type of annotation with Reflections

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, annotations

I'm trying to get a method with annotation @Before from MyTestClass. The class in the package named ru.package. It works fine when I have only 1 class with @Before. But if I create new classes and new classes in internal packages with this annotation and will try to find @Before annotations only from MyTestClass, this code give me all methods from all classes with this annotation, but i need just 1. Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().
                setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClass(MyTestClass.class)).
                setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));
Set<Method> methods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Before.class);
```

@Before annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Before {
}
```

MyTestClass.class

```
public class MyTestClass {

    private List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            stringList.add("string " + i);
        }
    }
    //@Test and etc
}
```

Comment: This isn't solution but maybe help you.  `Set<Method> methods =reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Before.class).stream().filter(method -> method.getDeclaringClass().equals(MyTestClass.class)).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: @HadiJ Yes, it can help, but I want to understand why I get methods from other classes, which should not happen) Thanks)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Indeed, `getMethodsAnnotatedWith` returns all the occurrences of the annotated methods. You can check the source code of `Reflections` class for that. If you wish to retrieve the occurrences for a single class, @HadiJ's advice is appropriate.

Comment: Scanning classes in the class path is the *purpose* of the Reflection library. If you just want to find a method of a single class, you don’t need a third party library: `Arrays.stream(MyTestClass.class .getDeclaredMethods()) .filter(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(Before.class)) .findFirst()`; that’s simpler than your code using that library.

Comment: I thought that my code will return to me only 1 method, but I was wrong. Thanks to everyone for their help.